# Swift optional inheritance from two classes

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, parse-platform

So I had a question that I'm not sure is totally possible.
For my local model I want to be able to inherit from one of two classes.

For example:
I have an event object that will have a name, location, attendees, etc. This object can either be downloaded from the backend (for which I'm using Parse) or created locally to be uploaded to the server.

If it is being downloaded, then it will be initialized with a parseObject, downloaded from the server. Parse provides a `createdAt` datetime, `objectID`, and `updatedTime` that I can use. But if I was to create the object locally to upload at some later time it would be superfluous to set these variables as I do not know what they will actually be (until my backend lazily loads those times and objectID into existence.

For storing these data types locally I was planning to have to objects, a `BaseParseObject` defined so:

```
class BaseParseObject: NSObject {
    var objectID: String
    var createdAt: NSDate
    var updatedAt: NSDate
    var className: String

    var timeSinceCreation: NSTimeInterval {
        get {
            return createdAt.timeIntervalSinceNow
        }
    }

    init(parseObject: PFObject) {
        self.objectID = parseObject.objectId!
        self.createdAt = parseObject.createdAt!
        self.updatedAt = parseObject.updatedAt!
        self.className = parseObject.parseClassName
    }
}
```

and a `baseObject` defined as:

```
class BaseObject: NSObject {
    var className: String

    init(className: String) {
        self.className = className
    }
}
```

I then have my event object, which can either be created locally to be uploaded or be downloaded from the server.
Is there any way to optionally inherit from both classes? Have just ONE Event class instead of two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no. Neither Swift nor Objective-C support multiple inheritance. You can get a similar effect using class extensions though. You CAN have a class implement multiple extensions.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand the extension implementation. Can you give me an example with the Event class that I mentioned?